# Is there a difference between el.Attribute ("...") and el.Attribute (XName.Get ("..."))?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute, xname

In our production code, I've seen XML attributes being read using explicit `XName.Get` call:

```
var name = element.Attribute (XName.Get ("name"));
```

I used to always pass a string to `Attribute`:

```
var name = element.Attribute ("name");
```

This is more readable but I wonder if there is any difference in logic or performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two parts to this:

**Are they calling the same `Attribute` method?**

Yes. There's only one [`XElement.Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) method, with an `XName` parameter, which means that in the latter case you are using the implicit string to `XName` conversion.

**Does the implicit string to `XName` conversion do the same as `XName.Get`?**

This isn't guaranteed - the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx) doesn't mention it. But I have no reason to doubt SLaks' analysis that the *current* implementation is the same.

---

Personally I *always* either use the conversion from string to `XName` or the addition operator between `XNamespace` and string to get an `XName`. I can't remember the last time I referred to it explicitly.

The conversions available are one of the beautiful things about LINQ to XML - it seems pointless to ignore them, IMO.

Comment: While SLaks' answer is strictly to the point, I mark yours as correct for some elaboration. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference whatsoever.
`XName` has an implicit cast from `string` which calls `XName.Get`.

You can see this in the source:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a string formatted as an expanded XML name ({namespace}localname) to an XName object. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expandedName">A string containing an expanded XML name in the format: {namespace}localname.</param> 
/// <returns>An XName object constructed from the expanded name.</returns> 
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static implicit operator XName(string expandedName) { 
    return expandedName != null ? Get(expandedName) : null;
}
```